# Panel data cointegration test: Package pco in R, how to interpret output from pedroni99 function?

Tags: r, econometrics, panel-data, cointegration

I have a panel dataset and I want to test cointegration between 2 variables. I cleaned the missing values and set my data frame as required but I don't know and can't find how to interpret the outcome from the Pedroni test on R,
the outcome looks like this:
[image]

And why do I have NaN in some cases ?
(I already read the documentation, help attached)

Comment: The null of the tests are no panel cointegration against the alternative of cointegration in at least one panel unit. You reject for negative values, critical values are in the paper of Pedroni. As to the NaNs, the most likely source to me is that, somewhere, the code tries to take the square root of a negative number, but the source of that problem is not easy to spot as it stands.